# Export-Counter missing from Powershell 7.1

Tags: powershell

Any idea how to export counters in Powershell 7.1.0?  The command is missing with the latest update.

```
Get-Command -Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-Counter                                        7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics
Cmdlet          Get-WinEvent                                       7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics
Cmdlet          New-WinEvent                                       7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics

❯ $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.1.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.1.0
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19042
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Comment: according to the MSDocs site,that cmdlet is currently only available with ps5.1 - you can see that here >>> Export-Counter (Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics) - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/export-counter?view=powershell-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7

Comment: When I change the version to 7.1 Export-Counter is no longer present in the document.  It looks like it is no longer supported beyond 5.1.  Is there a new way to perform this action in 7.1?  It seems odd that you can get the counters but now have an effective way to convert them to other data files.
Do I now need to reinvent the wheel with this lack of support?

Comment: as documented, ps6+ is "going to eventually include almost all that is in ps5.1". the emphasis goes on _eventually_ and _almost all_. [*grin*] ///// as for how to do it with ps7+ ... i would start a ps5.1 session and use that.